# If $a\mathrm{A^2}+b\mathrm{A}+c\mathrm{I}=\mathrm{O}$ and $\mathrm{X=P^{-1}AP}$, then proving $a\mathrm{X^2}+b\mathrm{X}+c\mathrm{I}=\mathrm{O}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I'm, struggling with a matrix question from my course. I have attached an image with the problem clearly typed, however; here is the typed up version of it:

> If $a\mathrm{A^2}+b\mathrm{A}+c\mathrm{I}=\mathrm{O}$ and $\mathrm{X=P^{-1}AP}$ , prove that $a\mathrm{X^2}+b\mathrm{X}+c\mathrm{I}=\mathrm{O}$.

Thank you

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please include your answer to my question IN your posted question (edit it).

Answer (score 4):

Hypotheses (1) and (2) are:$$\tag{1}aA^2+bA+cI=0$$

$$\tag{2}X= P^{-1} AP \ \ \ (a) \ \ \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ \ \ X^2= P^{-1} APP^{-1} AP=P^{-1} A^2P \ \ \ (b)$$

Left-multiply (1) by $P^{-1}$, right-multiply it by $P$ and use (2)a and (2)b (or not (2)b ?) to conclude:

$$\tag{3}aX^2+ bX+cI=0$$

Comment: Haha, I like the way you snuck Hamlet in there.  :) +1